# Did the five Robins ever meet each other in the comics?

Tags: dc, comics, robin

I saw on Google that Batman has had five different Robins in the comics, who had all left for their own reasons. Have they ever met each other in the comics? I don't mean just manage to catch a glimpse of another Robin, but have the five of them been together in a place and at least exchanged a couple of words?

Comment: While the four Robins meet quite often, Stephanie being part of the reunion is rarer. At least I assume that's who you meant as "fifth Robin" (I personally think she's not one, but well...)

Comment: There's also the Golden-Age (Earth-2) Robin, and I remember at least one Justice League/Justice Society story where he mentored the Earth-1 Robin.

Comment: Batman #15 - https://comicvine1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/original/12/121886/2754032-batman15_01.jpg

Comment: https://66.media.tumblr.com/797ab408c686b1d92ec73929bbc3a29f/67240e99fc740556-dd/s540x810/1c71a12a163c33ae8b30963009058f1dbd420669.jpg

Comment: @Valorum the first pic isn't it, this is Barbara (Batgirl), not Stephanie

Comment: @Jenayah - Indeed, hence posted as a comment.

Comment: Five? Nope! Dick, Jason, Tim, Damien, Stephanie and Carrie Kelly. And Duke if you count the "We are Robin" storyline. So six or seven; not five

Answer (score 10):

If we assume the five Robins to be Dick, Jason, Tim, Stephanie and Damian, then they meet in the same comic at least five times.

The first one is *Detective Comics* #1000 (2019) where the whole Bat-family is gathered up on a roof for a group photo. It's unclear whether they all talk to each other, but not unlikely.

[image: various Robin pairings exchanging trivialities]

The second one, much more on point, is  *Batman: Gotham Nights* #12 (2020), aptly titled "Five Little Robins". Basically the whole issue features all of them,

> even though Damian was impersonated by Clayface, but the real one eventually shows up.

[image: Damian being an insufferable little brat, confirming he's the real Damian]

The third one, also very on point, is the story "The Master Class" from *Detective Comics* #1027 (2020), where all these Robins (and Batgirl, and Batman) meet to investigate the same inexplicable murder, which they originally believe to be a set-up to test their detective skills. They all talk to each other.

[image: Batgirl, Red Hood, Robin, Nightwing, Spoiler and Red Robin standing on a glass roof, surrounding a corpse]

The fourth one is in *Robin* #5 (2021) when Damian, after seceding from Batman to run his own kind of justice, competes in the Lazarus tournament. While on the island, the four others come to his help after having been tipped by Ravager; Damian escapes most of them more or less easily.

[image: Rooftop chase between the five Robins]

The *Robins* title, launched in October 2021, features the five of them as protagonists.

[image: various Robins gathered at Dick Grayson's place in Blüdhaven, sitting around a table]

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

For one thing, there were more than 5 if you count spin-offs and one shots - like Carrie and  Julie. If you go back to the 1950s canon, Bruce was the original Robin when younger, but that got edited out in the 1980s sometime. The various universes and things also complicate it. Many people also argue that Stephanie doesn't count.

Pre-2011 re-write, Dick, Jason, Tim, Stephanie and Damien all met at various points. After the 2011 relaunch, Dick, Jason, Tim and Damien have all met up and met Stephanie too, but in that continuity, Stephanie is never Robin as far as I remember but they make Carrie (from *The Dark Knight Returns*) part of the canon Robins instead.

There are also other universe Robins, like Helena who doesn't exist in the main universe, and not to mention that age switch with Bruce and Tim where Bruce was Robin for a while...